# overall rank from three ranked tables in excel 2010

Tags: excel, ranking

I have three or four tables each of them having 4 to 7 columns.
all tables having "name" column common.
all tables having rank values but based on different columns. ie; rank values of each table differs. suppose in table1 name x got rank1, in second table name z got rank1 etc...

but I want to calculate the overall rank based on all ranking tables.
I mean, table1 can be weighed as 0.2, table2 weight 0.6 etc...so that I want to see overall rank of name x,y,z etc....
Is there any way in excel or any alternative software??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to weight the original "scores" not the ranks.

In another table you can use a VLOOKUP to get the score from each of the other tables, multiplied by the weight, e.g.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Table1,2,0)*0.6+VLOOKUP(A2,Table2,2,0)*0.2+VLOOKUP(A2,Table3,2,0)*0.2`

Where A2 is the name and assuming that each table has the name in one column followed by the score in the next.

Now you can simply rank the "new" scores

**Revised suggestion:**

Given your comments I think you could still do the same as my initial suggestion except weight the ranks - I don't see how that won't be valid even if some of your original ranks are in descending order and some in ascending order........but if your rank is to the left of the name you can't use VLOOKUP so I would switch to SUMIF (although INDEX/MATCH would also work, so this formula in H2 copied down gives a combined rank assuming weights of 0.6/0.2/0.2 (adjust as required)

`=SUMIF(C$2:C$4,G2,B$2:B$4)*0.6+SUMIF(C$7:C$9,G2,B$7:B$9)*0.2+SUMIF(C$12:C$14,G2,B$12:B$14)*0.2`

and then you can get the overall rank with this formula in I2 copied down:

`=RANK(H2,H$2:H$4,1)`

[image]

Comment: barry, I appreciate your responce.

Comment: barry, I appreciate your response. Currently I need to weigh ranks of table1,2,3&4 etc. I will use your suggestion when I need to weigh scores. Is there any way in excel to weigh ranks if "names" to get overall rank? In my tables I have scores for parameters

Comment: Well you can do exactly the same thing but use the VLOOKUPs to retrieve the rank instead of the score....

Comment: T1  
Rank Name P1
1 D3 22
2 D1 24
3 D2 27
  
T2  
Rank Name P2
1 D1 3569
2 D3  571
3 D2  34
  
T3  
Rank  Name P3
1 D2  8.2
2 D1  10.3
3 D3  30.5
These are my tables, if you see values some parameters are having rank 1 for highest value and some parameters having rank for lowest values. If you see D3, it is at rank 1,2 and 3 for different parameters. I don't want to change their values as if I multiply their values with weight and then rank will not give me desired output. since I have three ranks for parameters,how can I see them overall rank of D's for the corresponding values? pls advise.

Comment: @durga637 OK I put your data in a spreadsheet and created a 4th table to get a "combined rank" and then an "overall rank" - see "revised suggestion" in my answer - does that do what you want?